# Java: correct regex expression for dealing with the following string?

Tags: java, regex

```
String someXpath = "/a/b/c[3]/preceding-sibling::c[3]/a[2]";
someXpath.replaceAll("/preceding\\-sibling::(.*)\\//", ""));
```

basically I am trying to get `"/a/b/c[3]/a[2]";`

Comment: unless I'm confusing something, I think you want `replaceAll()`, not `replace()`. I think `replace()` is just literal strings, not reg-ex.

Comment: yes that is correct, replaceAll

Answer (score 1):

This will remove everything up to the next `/`.

```
someXpath.replaceAll("/preceding-sibling::[^/]*","")
```